# How to recover SA account password without restoring it?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I forgot my SA password and resetting the password is out of the question because internal applications are using it and will will affect them. I also don't have an option to change the SA credentials for those applications.

This is why I must know what the password is WITHOUT restoring it.

Is there any method for that?

Comment: look at the source code for the applications?

Comment: And why are your internal applications using sa? This is the first thing you need to change.

Comment: Concur with HLGEM (and +1).

Comment: @Ofir Find out a way to reset sa password and then create login/password for the apps that are using SA account, give the developers that new login/password and tell them it's a very bad practice to use the sa account for the app logins.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can retrieve the lost sa password without resetting it. Relevant SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196150/is-there-a-way-i-can-retrieve-sa-password-in-sql-server-2005)